# Filtering Columns in DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing a view with `System.DataTable` and from that the `html table` is rendered. The visibility of the columns varies with each `login`.

(ie) consider there are 5 columns as `colA`, `colB`, `colC`, `colD`, `colE` and these columns visibility varies with each login. Some login have only `colA` and some have `colA` and `colD` and some have all.

Here is the implementation which works fine for the above requirment

`sql procedure` will return all these columns with a `bit` field column for each column to show/hide that column in a view like this.

`colA`, `isColA`, `colB`, `isColB` and so on

Filtering actually stars here in **`controller`**

```
DataTable dt = "Method here that will generate datatable";
var cols = new string[] { "colA", "isColA", "colB", "isColB", "colC", "isColC" and so on };
var colsRemove = new List<string> { };

for(int i=0; i < cols.Length; i +=2)
{
     colsRemove.Add(dt.Columns[cols[i + 1]].ToString());
     if(!dt.Rows[0][cols[i + 1]].Equals(true))
     {
         colsRemove.Add(dt.Columns[cols[i]].ToString());
         colsRemove.Add(dt.Columns[cols[i + 1]].ToString());
     }
 }

 var newDt = new DataTable();
 newDt = dt.Clone();

 foreach(var item in colsRemove)
 {
     newDt.Columns.Remove(item);
 }

 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
     newDt.ImportRow(row);
 }
```

This works fine and here is my actual question,

1. whether the implementation is a standard practice?
2. Is there any other simplest way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Standard practice would be to modify the SQL used to generate the DataTable, so that only the columns needed are included in the query. Your method works, but it's inefficient because all columns are returned for every login, whether they're used or not. However, you're already in a world of inefficiency because you're using a DataTable to generate HTML (this would not be a good design for a high-volume site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell whether this is a standard practice, but I would use DynamicObject instead.
Here is blog post to give you some ideas about DynamicObect, it is worth reading about ExpandoObject as well.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/19/dynamic-in-c-4-0-creating-wrappers-with-dynamicobject.aspx

Here is a LinqPad snippet

```
void Main()
{
    List<dynamic> flexibleList = new List<dynamic>();
    dynamic aa = new FlexibleTable();
    aa.ColumnA = "testA";
    aa.ColumnB="testB";
    flexibleList.Add(aa);
    aa = new FlexibleTable();
    aa.ColumnA = "testA1";
    aa.ColumnB="testB1";
    flexibleList.Add(aa);
    foreach(dynamic item in flexibleList){
      foreach(var columnName in item.VisibleColumns){

         new object[]{item[columnName]}.Dump();

      }
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class FlexibleTable: DynamicObject{
 private Dictionary<string,object> Columns{get; set;}
 public FlexibleTable(){
   this.Columns = new Dictionary<string,object>();
 }
  public  override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result){
   if(Columns.ContainsKey(binder.Name)){
        result = Columns[binder.Name];
        return true;
   }else{
        result = null;
        return false;
        }
  }
  public  override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value){
    Columns[binder.Name] = value;
    return true;
  }

  public override bool TryGetIndex(
        GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
    {

        string index = (string)indexes[0];
        return Columns.TryGetValue(index , out result);
    }


  public IEnumerable<string> VisibleColumns{
     get{   return Columns.Select(x=>x.Key);}
  }

}
```